# Alpine and docker:20.10.22 unable to install pip3

Tags: python-3.x, docker, gitlab, alpine-linux

I am upgrading some images from to `docker:19.03.5` to `docker:20.10.22` but am hitting issues when my `Push Dev` job tries to install `pip3` on the image being used by `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Initially I was not explicitly installing `pip3` as this worked fine, after an initial error saying `pip3` was not installed I tried installing using `apk` as below.

```
before_script:
  - apk add python3
  - apk add python3-pip
  - pip3 install awscli==1.18.8
  - docker load --input data/image.tar
  - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)


Push Dev:
  stage: Push
  script:
    - docker tag proxy:latest $ECR_REPO:dev
    - docker push $ECR_REPO:dev
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'"
```

However I still get this issue. Any idea what is wrong here?

```
$ apk add python3
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/11) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r4)
(2/11) Installing libexpat (2.5.0-r0)
(3/11) Installing libffi (3.4.4-r0)
(4/11) Installing gdbm (1.23-r0)
(5/11) Installing xz-libs (5.2.9-r0)
(6/11) Installing libgcc (12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
(7/11) Installing libstdc++ (12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
(8/11) Installing mpdecimal (2.5.1-r1)
(9/11) Installing readline (8.2.0-r0)
(10/11) Installing sqlite-libs (3.40.1-r0)
(11/11) Installing python3 (3.10.9-r1)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r29.trigger
OK: 65 MiB in 34 packages
$ apk add python3-pip
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  python3-pip (no such package):
    required by: world[python3-pip]
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: `python3-pip` is the name of the package under Debian and its derivates, on Alpine, it is named [`py3-pip`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.17/community/armv7/py3-pip).

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment made by β.εηοιτ.βε, I changed the name of the pip3 package to `py3-pip` to be in line with the expected package name in `alpine` instead of `python3-pip` which is Debian.

```
before_script:
  - apk add python3
  - apk add py3-pip
  - pip3 install awscli==1.18.8
  - docker load --input data/image.tar
  - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
```

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.17/community/armv7/py3-pip